# How to monitor a serial port without opening it on windows 7?

Tags: python, serial-port, windows-7-x64

I have developed a serial communication program in python and am returning a timestamp when the data actually is sent over the serial port.

I want to match this time stamp manually by monitoring the same port parallely through a program equivalent to something like PortMon. I am using Windows 7, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you specify more info about your problem? The system system you've developed was made in Python? Or you want to create a portmon in Python?

Comment: The system is in Python. I need to manually see the activities on the port when my Python programming is running.